# Testing Website On Different Device Extension/Tools

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've been trying to test my site on different mobile devices.

I'm currently using Google Chrome's 'resize window' to test on different devices, but they don't seem to match up.

For e.g. When I select the IPad view it looks fine but then when I get an actual IPad and look for the text isn't aligned properly.

I've tried Screenfly and some other tools also having the same problem.

Are these solutions reliable? How do you test across multiple devices to ensure it looks fine on all?

Thanks!

Comment: Check http://opendevicelab.com for a place near you. They are built for things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's for a small project I only check with build in Fire Fox Developer - Responsive design view option.
If the project is important, profitable and every detail matters the best solution for me is to try on real devices. If you are not so shy, go to a big electronic shop which has a lot of mobile devices for a test. In my country we have 2 big brand with maybe a hundred mobile devices connected to internet. After every bigger project I go to one of the shops and just "testing" the mobile devices, if someone asks. :) Of course sometimes I "forget" to close the browser which is opened on my website. :)

Comment: I like your approach for testing. Good luck.

Comment: Haha awesome.. Let's have a look at some of your sites...I might try that!

Answer (score 0):

[Browserstack](https://www.browserstack.com/%22Browser%20stack%22) and [Browserling](https://www.browserling.com/) look like promissing solutions. the former support cross device testing and has advanced options while the latter is a simple crossbrowser testing suite.

It all comes down to your requirement and budget